# is there a way to update size of button through interface builder?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, uibutton

I want my buttons twice as big when iPhone 5 launches on screen, is there a way to do this using the interface builder? Or do I have to do this pragmatically?

Comment: You can have two views in the sabe xib (one with iPhone 4S screen and another with iPhone 5 screen) and load the properly view with a bit of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is such a solution in Interface Builder. Pragmatically is the option for you.

But why do you need it?

**EDIT:**

You can manage spacing by `View` submenu in `Show and Size Inspector` (<kbd>Option / Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd>). See Autosizing and example windows next to it.

[image]

Here are Apple's docs regarding this topic (point 8.f): [Xcode Quick Start Guide - UI](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_quick_start/020-Tutorial_Designing_a_User_Interface_with_Interface_Builder/interface_builder_tutorial.html)

Comment: looks a bit off when comparing 3.5 inch screen to 4 inch screen. There seems to be a lot of spacing. The only problem is I want to use an image for buttons as well.